# Adding a center button to a UITabBar SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, tabbar

I would like to add a main button to a UITabBar as shown in the image:
[main button, the button i wish to add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aStci.png)
meaning i would like to add a button in the center of the bar, the button will be a bit higher then the other buttons( the regular buttons of an UITabBar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Interface Builder:

1. Drag a UIButton to the view
2. Set the size constraints (ex: width 80, height 80)
3. Align Center X to Superview
4. Align Bottom to Tab Bar: -20

In your View Controller:

1. Add an IBOutlet for the button
2. Then in `viewDidLoad` under `super.ViewDidLoad()` add:

   `button.layer.zposition = 1`

It should give you this result:

[image]

You can lower the image by increasing the negative number on the bottom constraint.

Comment: thanks, but is there a way to create a view like that in a class or something? because i need to implement it in multiple CVs.

Comment: I can inherit from UIViewController and create my costum VC that creates this UIButton, but is it the right way?